# Как проанализировать изображение в Python?

Tags: python

Есть изображение , надо узнать какой пиксель стоит на заданом месте , можете подсказать библотеку или метод.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Способов много. Есть например два модуля image, PIL.
[Читаем](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/CS152f17/MoreAboutIteration/2DimensionalIterationImageProcessing.html) пиксел при помощи image:

```
import image

img = image.Image("picture.jpg")

for row in range(img.getHeight()):
    for col in range(img.getWidth()):
        p = img.getPixel(col, row)
        print(p.getRed(),p.getGreen(),p.getBlue())
```

[Читаем](https://habr.com/post/163663/) пиксел при помощи PIL:

```
from PIL import Image  #Подключим необходимые библиотеки. 
image = Image.open("temp.jpg") #Открываем изображение. 
width = image.size[0] #Определяем ширину. 
height = image.size[1] #Определяем высоту.  
pix = image.load() #Выгружаем значения пикселей.
print (pix[4,4])
```

Будьте внимательны! это работает для файлов типа *".jpg"*.
У файлов *".gif"* своя кодировка цвета и файл прийдетса сначала [преобразовать:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064786/get-pixels-rgb-using-pil).

```
im = Image.open('image.gif')
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
r, g, b = rgb_im.getpixel((1, 1))

print(r, g, b)
```

а по ссылкам по слову "Читаем" прочтете интересные статьи по теме.
Увы - модули нестандартные, их придетса установить.

Answer (score 2):

В этом поможет библиотека [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.x/)

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("img.jpg") # Открываем изображение
pix = image.load()            # Выгружаем значения пикселей

x = 100 
y = 150 

print(pix[x, y])              # Выводим RGB пикселя с координатами (x,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще несколько способов прочитать файл изображения в Numpy массив.

Метод [skimage.io.imread()](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imread) из модуля `skimage` позволяет прочитать изображение практически любого популярного формата в 3D Numpy массив, где каждый пиксель представлен кортежем интенсивности цветов - RGB (Red Green Blue).

Пример:

```
from skimage.io import imread
filename = r'D:\download\picture.jpg'
img = imread(filename)

print(type(img))        #   <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(img.shape)        #   (2420, 2436, 3)
print(img[100, 100])    #   [177 173 161]
```

Также можно воспользоваться методом [cv2.imread()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html) из модуля OpenCV.
Данный метод также возвращает 3D Numpy массив, но вместо RGB он возвращает данные в формате BGR (Blue Green Red).

Пример:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread(filename)

print(type(im))        #   <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(im.shape)        #   (2420, 2436, 3)
print(im[100, 100])    #   [161 173 177]
```